# site domain issue in Django project

Tags: python, django

I started django server with following command:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.31.79:8030
```

when I use following code,

```
   from django.contrib.sites.models import Site 
   current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
   print (current_site.domain)
```

the result will be 192.168.31.79:**8000**, why not port is 8030? Anyone could explain it for me? how could I retrieve 192.168.31.79:8030 via coding. many thanks.

Comment: `current_site = Site.objects.get_current()` this won't get you the current active domain . it will get the active object of the model Site using SITE_ID variable in Django settings 
 please have a look at these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808972/find-host-and-port-in-a-django-application , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 0):

When resolving the `Site` with `get_current` Django will first check if a `SITE_ID` is set in the settings file. If there is a `SITE_ID` it will return what is stored in the `domain` field (obtaining the cached version in `SITE_CACHE` or adding it to the cache and returning it).

If `SITE_ID` is not present Django will resolve the host with `request.get_host()` and first query to see if the `domain` exists within the cache then check if it is in a `Site` object.

If this does not produce a result it will remove the `port` and check again in the same manner.

I would try looking at each of your `Site` objects to see if the port has made it into the `domain`. If not look into what is being stored in `SITE_CACHE`.

Documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.shortcuts.get_current_site